# Derivative with respect to the Frenet frame

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry

Given a regular smooth curve $\alpha: I \to \mathbb{R}^3$, we have that the Frenet Frame $\vec{t},\vec{n},\vec{b}$ is an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ at each point $s \in I$, and hence we can write $\alpha(s) = f_1(s) \vec{t}(s) +f_2(s) \vec{n}(s) + f_3(s) \vec{b}(s)$.

Given a generic function $g: I \to \mathbb{R}^n$ we define $\lim\limits_{s \to a} g = (\lim\limits_{s \to a} g_1,...,\lim\limits_{s \to a} g_n)$ and hence the derivative (with respect to $s$) is given component-wise. Can we also do this with the Frenet frame? Or must we consider $f_1 \vec{t}$ as a product?

In short, when do we consider the Frenet frame as a basis as opposed to as functions?

Answer (score 0):

The Frenet frame is a basis in the tangent space $T_p \mathbb{R}^3$ at a point $p = \alpha(s)$ on the curve. The tangent space  $T_p \mathbb{R}^3$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^3$, but this isomorphism varies from  point to point, and has nothing to do with the original space $\mathbb{R}^3$ in which you curve lives. Therefore, expanding the element of this original $\mathbb{R}^3$ in terms of the Frenet frame of the curve (at a point!) makes no sense.

As I understand the rest of your question, you are wondering whether an analogue of the Frenet frame is possible in higher dimensions. Of course, this is the case, see e.g. [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet%E2%80%93Serret_formulas).